# Parsing json correctly using GSON and Java

Tags: java, string, gson

This is my json string as I want to convert it to Java Class:

```
"result": {
    "id": "39559",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Who",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": null,
    "email": "john.who@roberts.com",
    "phone": null,
    "website": null,
    "address": null,
    "status": "active",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users/39559"
        },
        "edit": {
            "href": "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users/39559"
        },
        "avatar": {
            "href": null
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my class (I removed the getters and toString):

```java
public class Result {
    String id, user_id, title, first_name, last_name, gender, dob, email, phone,
            website, address, status, _links, album_id, url, thumbnail, post_id, name, body;
}
```

I wonder how can I represent

```
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users/39559"
    },
    "edit": {
        "href": "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users/39559"
    },
    "avatar": {
        "href": null
    }
}
```

How can I represent the missing part in my Result class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_links` seems to be a JSON Object with attributes `self`, `edit` and `avatar`. Each of these attributes are JSON Objects too, all having attribute `href`. → You need these three classes for representing those objects:

```java
public class Result {
    String id, user_id, title, first_name, last_name, gender;
    String dob, email, phone, website, address, status;
    String album_id, url, thumbnail, post_id, name, body;
    Links _links;
}
```

```java
public class Links {
    Link self, edit, avatar;
}
```

```java
public class Link {
    String href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create Links as object with fields